# Graph optimization phase in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm using tensorflow for inference, on a freezed and optimized DNN.
I optimized the DNN for deployment using the instructions at this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#optimizing-for-deployment).
However, tracing the execution of tensorflow I noticed that tensorflow is still optimizing at runtime (calling GraphExecutionState::OptimizeGraph). Is there any way to avoid this behavior?